# Storing data struct

Tags: c++

I am running this program well, but every time I exit it and run again, all the data in the matrix data[] is lost. Is there any way to keep this data so when I run it again I can check it?
(Sorry if this question is too simple, I've started coding few weeks ago)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int TRUE = 1;
static int n = 0;


struct Restaurant{
    char name[30];
    char address[50];
    float price;
    char food[20];
};

Restaurant data[10];

void inputData(void);
void outputData(void);

    int main()
{
    char option;

    cout << "============Welcome to Restaurant Interface!============\n" << endl;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Type \'A\' to add a restaurant data " << endl;
        cout << "     \'S\' to search for restaurants "<< endl;
        cout << "  or \'E\' to exit" << endl;
        option = getch();

        switch (option)
        {
            case ('a'):
            case ('A'):             
                inputData();
                break;
            case ('s'):
            case ('S'):
                outputData();
                break;
            case ('e'):
            case ('E'):
                cout << "\n\n==============================================================\n\n";
                cout << "Thanks for using Restaurant Interface! See you soon mate!" << endl;
                exit(0);
            default:
                cout << "\nInvalid option. please choose again\n";                  
        }

        cout << "\n\n==============================================================\n\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void inputData()
{
    cout << "\n\n==============================================================\n\n";
    char temp[80];
    cout << "Type the name of your restaurant: "; gets(data[n].name);

    cout << "Type the address of your restaurant: "; gets(data[n].address);

    cout << "Type the price range: "; gets(temp);
    data[n].price = atof(temp);

    cout << "Type the style of food: "; gets(data[n].food);;

    cout << "New restaurant data added successfully!!!" << endl;

    n++;    
}

void outputData()
{
    cout << "\n\n==============================================================\n\n";
    if(!n)
    {
        cout << "Empty list." << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "Restaurant list" << endl;
    cout << left << setw(20) << "Name";
    cout << left << setw(30) << "Address";
    cout << left << setw(15) << "Average Price";
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Type of cuisine" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(20) << data[i].name;
        cout << left << setw(30) << data[i].address;
        cout << "R$" << left << setw(15) << data[i].price;
        cout << left << setw(10) << data[i].food << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean you want to serialize your inputs to a file, and restore (deserialize) them from another run of your program?

Comment: Everytime you start a program and initialize a variable, it's stored in your memory. When variable goes out of scope or you simply exit program your variable is cleared from memory. If you want to keep your data you need to store it inside a file.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], with emphasis on the *"minimal"*.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs don't keep any data accessible that was stored in their local memory between different runs.

Declaring global data like in

```
Restaurant data[10];
```

doesn't overcome this restriction. The global will be instantiated and initialized at every new run of the program, data gathered from former runs is lost.

If you want to keep that data you need to have some kind of persistence mechanism, like de-/serializing that data to/from a file or database table.

Answer (score 0):

C++ erases every data when program finishes executing. If you want to save information created during execution of the program the easiest and simplier way is using data files. [Here is some information about](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)